# feols command in R difference with fixed effects

Tags: r

I am using the feols command in R and the following happens, if I run:

```
result <- feols(y ~  x1 + x2  | ID + month, cluster = "state", data=dataset)
```

It doesn't estimate x2 because of collinearity problem, okay, weird.

But, if I try the following:

```
result <- feols(y ~  x1 + x2  + as.factor(ID)|  month, cluster = "state", data=dataset)
```

it estimates x2.

Does anyone knows what might be happening?

Thank you!